# Find the mean of y per grouped value of x

Tags: r

I have following problem: 
I have a data.frame with two columns. I will 'find the mean of y per grouped value of x'[formulation from hrbrmstr] . Example:

```
 x <- c(1,4,4,2,1,3,4,2,3,4)
 y <- c(2.23,5.56,5.53,3.32,2.32,4.21,5.60,3.43,4.32,5.59)
 my.data <- data.frame(x,y)   

> my.data
x    y
1  1 2.23
2  4 5.56
3  4 5.53
4  2 3.32
5  1 2.32
6  3 4.21
7  4 5.60
8  2 3.43
9  3 4.32
10 4 5.59
```

If I calculate it manually it is:

```
xx <- c(1,2,3,4)
yy <- c(mean(c(2.23,2.32)),mean(c(3.32,3.43)),mean(c(4.21,4.32)),mean(c(5.56,5.53,5.60,5.59)))
my.data.corr <- data.frame(xx,yy)
```

The result data.frame should be:

```
> my.data.corr
xx    yy
1  1 2.275
2  2 3.375
3  3 4.265
4  4 5.570
```

The order of xx in the result doesn't matter.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You look to be just taking the first `y` for each `x` value. Is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to find the mean of `y` per grouped value of `x` your example output is wrong.

```
 library(dplyr)

 my.data %>%
   group_by(x) %>%
   summarise(yy=mean(y))

##   x    yy
## 1 1 2.275
## 2 2 3.375
## 3 3 4.265
## 4 4 5.570
```

If you're trying to do something else, please re-phrase your question.

Comment: That's exactly what I want!!! You're right our outputs are different, even if I don't understand why there is a difference between our calculations?

Comment: You are completely right! My mistake was that I used  'mean(4.21,4.32)' instead of 'mean(c(4.21,4.32))', sorry about that and many thanks for your answer!